# Get programmingLanguage and topic for Github repo via API

Tags: github-api

How can I get the **repo-language** and **topic** for a Github Repo through the REST API. I looked at the documentation under - https://developer.github.com/v3/ , but could not get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just found one way to do the search for topics as follows. Of course it needs a custom media type at moment.

From the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/):

```
curl -H "Authentication: token TOKEN" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json" \
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:ruby+topic:rails
```

For the language, it is simply the URL like :

`https://api.github.com/repos/postgres/pgadmin4/languages`